# activating function in swift file from an objective-C file

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

I'm working on an app (in Xcode with storyboard and written in swift) but for a Reward ad (from AdMob) I had to use an Objective-C file to handle that certain view controller in objective-C. As a reward for clicking the ad I wanted to give the person coins in the app but the label which displays the coins is in another view controller in swift (both linked with a navigation controller).

After searching the internet I couldn't find a solution, but here is what I have already:

In the swift file for rewarding the user (named "RewardingUserAds.swift"):

```
import Foundation

@objc class RewardingUserAds: NSObject {
    
    @objc func call_increase_score() {
        
        print("Rewarding user ads is called.")
        
        Winkel_ViewController().increase_score()
    }
}
```

I found on internet you should use NSObject and add '@objc' that's why I have it there now, this calls a function in 'Winkel_Viewcontroller' which increases the variable of the coin.

A snippet from my objective-C file ('Ad_ViewController.m') ( I have not changed the 'Ad_ViewController.h'file) which gives the error:

```
#import "Ad_ViewController.h"
#import "Troeven-Bridging-Header.h"
#import "Troeven-Swift.h"

@import GoogleMobileAds;

@interface Ad_ViewController ()


@property(nonatomic, strong) GADRewardedAd *rewardedAd;

@end

@implementation Ad_ViewController

...

    -(void) rewardedAd:(GADRewardedAd *)rewardedAd userDidEarnReward:(GADAdReward *)reward {
    
    RewardingUserAds *obj = [RewardingUserAds alloc];
    [obj call_increase_score];
    
    
    NSLog(@"User earned reward!");

}
```

The problem occurs in the second to last line ([obj call_increase_score] -> with ‘call_increase_score’ the function in the swift file it should activate/call). The error (red) is labeled as: 'No visible @interface for 'RewardingUserAds' declares the selector 'call_increase_score'' and that whole line stays white collored

[image]

I have a bridgehead between them named : 'Troeven-Bridging-Header.h' which is empty. I got little to no experience in objective-C which makes it harder for me to find the mistake I make. Can someone help?

Comment: I haven't used AdMob, but a quick look at the "Getting Started" docs doesn't indicate that you need to use Objective-C ... what makes you think that you do?

Comment: The sdk that is used from google for the ads has been updated this year which depreciated the old ways to integrate it. The google development page with the guide how to add the reward based ad only shows info on how to add it in objective-C. After trying for about a day to let it work in swift, I was unsuccessful. So, I followed the guide with the objective-C code which was successful from the first time. Now the only problem I have is giving the reward ( by adding += 1 to a variable in a regular swift viewcontroller).

Comment: That sounds very odd, but... in your `-(void) rewardedAd: ...` method, if you start typing `RewardingU` does Xcode auto-complete it for you?

Comment: I'm adding a photo to the post above, this is the error I get. I really don't know much about objective-C but it seems to not link the second line with the above one, or at least doesn't find the function I'm referring to.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:
had to remove '#import "Troeven-Bridging-Header.h"'

and change:

```
RewardingUserAds *obj = [RewardingUserAds alloc];
    [obj call_increase_score];
```

to:

```
RewardingUserAds *client = [RewardingUserAds new];
    [client call_increase_score];
```

-> I don't really know why it works, but it works